# Can variables be used within web.xml to conditionally show error-pages?

Tags: java, weblogic, web.xml, weblogic11g

My application has a maximum amount of concurrent sessions defined within its weblogic.xml:

```
<session-descriptor>  
  <max-in-memory-sessions>0</max-in-memory-sessions>
</session-descriptor>
```

any more sessions will produce a `weblogic.servlet.SessionCreationException`. I've defined an `<error-page>`-tag in wem.xml to handle this error and navigate to some error page:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>weblogic.servlet.SessionCreationException</exception-type>
  <location>/errorPage.html</location>
</error-page>
```

I would like to refer to two different error-pages based on either some Java bean or, if necessary, URL-parsing. Extending the SessionCreationException in order to catch different errors in my web.xml isn't an option; I don't want to modify internal weblogic classes (in this case, the error is thrown by `weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext.checkSessionCount`).

Can I use variables in web.xml? If so, can I use them to fit my purpose?

Comment: instead of using an html page (errorPage.html) you can use a servlet or a jsp in which you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will read up on that and do my worst.